# Windows Azure website disk space

Tags: azure

I have a website running in windows azure in shared mode and I am fairly content with it. But then I noticed that I have only 1Gb of available disk space, which is by far not enough. So I wanted to upscale, but found out that there are 2 options that are both not good:

1) Upscaling to reserved mode gives 10Gb but for all the websites that will run there, what? The cheapest hosting options out there give more diskspace for *one* website. Besides, this does not make sense to me, as I am pretty content with the speed of the shared modus.

2) Use of blob storage. So I need to rewrite my code to accommodate azure? Should it not be the other way around? For me one of the most important reasons to chose for azure above traditional webhosting was the promise of easy upscaling, but my first moment of upscaling, and it can't be done easily.

Am I missing something, is there a better way for getting more disk space for a windows azure website?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Definitely use blob storage, the actual azure web servers aren't supposed to be used for storage persistence. Using blob storage will allow be better upscaling.

The azure web servers are designed to handle volitile deployments. They are designed to house only your application/service and give you flexibility to easily create & destroy instances of them. Given this flexibility, if you store stuff on the actual you run the risk of losing this information as you scale up, down and around.

Then there is the other case where if you had two azure web servers running... request #1 goes off to server #1 and uploads a file. This obviously will get saved to the #1 servers hard disk drive. Now if that same #1 user comes back a second time (or any user for that matter) but this time gets load balanced to server #2 and requests that file - how does server #2 know where to get that file from?

Basically, saving files to the hard drive of the webserver creates a scalability issue. To get around this issue, you must save all your files to a centralised location... that is where Azure Blob storage comes into play.

Azure wasn't designed as a magic unicorn that you just throw your application at and it magically scales... you need to have a slight shift in mindset from single server application to an application that could be running on multiple servers all over the world all requiring the same data from a centralized location.

Comment: I see what you're saying. It makes sense, but what about speed? If I have say 20 images on a page, how would blob storage effect the speed?

Comment: It depends how you go about getting them... you have two options. **#1** You have a get method on your own website which then fetches the image from blob storage and serves it up itself. **#2** You can set blob storage to be public so that you just set your img src directly at blob storage url. The second option is preferable... this will then have additional added benefits that you can setup your blob storage as a CDN to further improve performance - see here: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/cdn/

Comment: I'll try out the second option